# how to use 2-way binding in angular 9

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to bind each item of an array to *[(ngModel)]* of a text box.

**component.ts**
`arr:string[] = ["",""];`

**component.html [FIRST APPROACH]**

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of arr;">
      <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item">
      </div>
    </div>
```

First Approach fires error, it was working fine in angular 7:
*Cannot use variable 'item' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only.*

**component.html [SECOND APPROACH]**

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of arr; let i = index">
      <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="arr[i]">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Second approach works but the input:text box loss focus after typing a single letter.

Can somebody provide me a perfect approach for similar scenarios?

Comment: produce a stackblitz

Comment: How do you want it to display in the textbox. If it's as a comma-separated list of values, I would use arr.join(", ") and set this value to the binded variable and then use myVar.split(',') in the controller when an array is needed.

Comment: I should be able to change value of each item in the array via the text box

Comment: You can do that using this method, and probably trim() to take awat the whitspace, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use trackby

in compoment :

```
trackByFn(index: any, item: any) {
    return index;
  }
```

in html :

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of arr; let i = index ; trackBy:trackByFn">
      <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="arr[i]">
      </div>
    </div>
```

stackblitz link for demo :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwyrs9

Please let me know if it is not working

Comment: That's great to hear bro.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why this is needed in the first place?